# Orchard Multi-tenant theme not enabled

Tags: multi-tenant, orchardcms

When trying to change to a theme installed by the parent of the tenant website in Orchard, it is not possible to change or preview the theme.

In the parent website, the theme shows as enabled (it can only be disabled), it previews correctly and can be switched to etc but in the tenant website, it is not possible to do either of these and it appears to be disabled (the "enable" link is shown).

So in the tenant website when you click preview on an installed theme in the themes admin section, you just get a 404 - request not found for /Admin/Themes/Preview/

Machine specifics:
Orchard v.1.1.30.0 (zip file installation pointed to in IIS) on IIS7.5, windows7, using hosts file entries to fake the domain names.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please file a bug: http://orchard.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create

Comment: Fair enough.  I haven't tried multi-tenancy before (or Orchard much for that matter) so I presumed it was my setup.  I'll file a bug and try and download the previous version of Orchard. Thanks.

Comment: Not much of a bug IMO. I was setting up multiple sites in IIS, using the same app pool and pointing them at the same virtual directory which was a bit daft! Adding multiple domain name bindings to the same application in IIS works just fine and that's how you would normally set it up.  Not sure on why that causes a problem for Orchard but I can't imagine many people would want to set up multiple websites rather than just editing the bindings of the one website.